# Regex - Not matching NewLine when it should?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Promise, last of my Regex questions for a while. ..Really.

I'm somehow getting newlines into some matches when I shouldn't, and I'm sure that it's something I'm misinterpreting, OR, the data I'm getting isn't what I expect. (Which IS possible..!)

I have a regex defined:
`new Regex(@"^\s*[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[\s\*]\s*(?<token>.*?)\-(?<value>.*?)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);`

My document/string I get is formatted with the occasional line like:

```
0000AA Token1     - Value
0000AA Token2     - Value
0000AA Token3     - Value
0000AA Another Tok- Value
```

When I get all the tokens in order like this, the above regex works great. I get four matches:

```
Match# <token> <value>
1      Token1      Value
2      Token2      Value
3      Token3      Value
4      Another Tok Value
```

This is good. However, sometimes the user will send me a file where the tokens have the occasional missing line, as in:

```
0000AA Token1     - Value
0000AA Token2     - Value
0000AA Token3     - Value
0000AA
0000AA Another Tok- Value
```

When this happens, my regex will give me the following values:

```
Match# <token>           <value>
1      Token1             Value
2      Token2             Value
3      Token3             Value
4      0000AA Another Tok Value
```

I know why, it's matching the #4's token starting with the line above it. However, when I change the 'token' grouping to `(?<token>[^\n]*?)`, I still get the same value in 'token'.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, because if . was matching newlines when it shouldn't, more folks than I would be raisins a ruckus over it. I have checked the incoming string - newlines ARE `\n`, and not `\r\n`, but wondering if something else could be the problem.

Cheers again -
Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the **\s** after the alphanumeric code at the beginning; **\s** also matches newline, and you don't want to. You basically need to match **\s** AND NOT **\n**. This is not expressible with regular expression, but if you use the DeMorgan theorem, you can rewrite this expression:

```
\s AND NOT \n = NOT(NOT \s OR \n)
```

It turns out the **NOT \s** can be written **\S**:

```
\s AND NOT \n = NOT(NOT \s OR \n) = NOT(\S OR \n)
```

This is easily expressible as a regular expression:

```
\s AND NOT \n = NOT(NOT \s OR \n) = NOT(\S OR \n) = [^\S\n]
```

Hence, instead of **\s** use **[^\S\n]**, which means *match everything except newline, and the negation of \s*.

I did a few other changes in the same area because I felt like that some stuff was not necessary. You can add it back if you think it is.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[^\S\n]*(?<token>.*?)\-(?<value>.*?)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I feel like a dunce - I never realized that a newline was considered whitespace. (Tho, it does make sense!)  Good tip on the double-negation, too - I had never thought of it that way.

Thanks!